# How do I dynamically load styles for a React app?

Tags: css, reactjs, redux, react-router

I want to create app that have this usecases:

1. Load dynamically style from some theme.
2. End user can define some theme with html, css, ... and install on the app.

After some research for choosing best solution for this problem we find out for state management we need some library or framework like `Redux` or `mobx`. For dynamically styling we decide to use [fela](http://fela.js.org/).

this is supposed to be a shop app that can have different themes. user can change the theme and customize it to some degree. that's why we need to have some sort of dynamic style loading. components are the same.

Comment: ["If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @trixn: I changed it. only need advice on dynamic style loading

Comment: Can't say anything about fela because i didn't use it yet. But i guess it would do the job. But no idea if it is the fastest or best maintained or has the best api. Alternatives are e.g. [glamour](https://github.com/threepointone/glamor) or [aphrodite](https://github.com/Khan/aphrodite) an a bunch of others. Anyways there is a lot of discussion going on about using css in javascript at the moment and what is the best approach witch component based frameworks.

Comment: Radium is another alternative: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium